# mgraph javascript style_dashed arrow style

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

is there a way to make the arrow connector to be dotted/dashes? been reading the js/xml and couldn't get my head around where to set it.

when you drag an arrow it shows standard straight line but instead i want something "---->".

I know svg takes something like the code below to have a dotted/dash line

```
<path stroke-dasharray="10,10" d="M5 40 l215 0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Styles in mxGraph are set on the cells ([see user manual](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/manual.html#3.1.3.1)).

Setting an edge to dash style is `dashed=1;`